# Arch/Manjaro Linux - Can't save applications sessions

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro

Since I updated to the last build of Manjaro (16.08), all my browsers and even my Telegram account info aren't stored for future usage. So everytime I reboot the system, I have to sign in to all my stuff all over again.

I have already checked for the permissions of `.TelegramDesktop`, and it seems OK.

Any idea of what to do?

Comment: What browsers?  Have you tried creating a new browser user profile or reinstalling the browser?

Comment: Opera, Chrome, Chromium, Firefox. All of them. Yep, I've tried reinstalling too. And it gets me nowhere

Comment: Any other symptoms?  Any other kinds of applications not saving?  Where are the profiles located (i.e., in/under the home directory)?  Can you try rolling it back to the previous version to confirm the cause?

Comment: I just mentioned the build, because before I buy a new note book and install the system on it, my old notebook was working really fine with the last build. I don't know if it is something with the system itself or with the apps permissions. The user data is stored under the `.config` directory.

Comment: Where is .config located (somewhere under the home directory)?  What you describe sure smells like a permissions problem.

Comment: Yeah. the `.config` folder is under the `/home/hiagop` directory.

Comment: I don't understand really well how to read the permission status of files and folders. But I'm searching for it right now, to figure out what's happening.